# change my application that works with mongodb on mongolab

Tags: mongodb, scala, heroku, mlab, scalate

I am working on Eclipse with a small scala/scalatra application.. at first I worked with mongodb installed on eclipse (locally) my application is running and everything is good but when I wanted to deploy my application on heroku I found http 503 error.

I think the problem is in my database, is what I need to change my connection with my base mongolab https://mongolab.com or should I add mongolab at heroku.

for connection mongodb I did:

```
    val mongo = MongoConnection()
val coll = mongo("db_test")("tache2")
```

How can I change my code so I can have it connected to my account mongolab??

Answer (score 0):

You should create your uri like this:

```
val uri = MongoURI(s"mongodb://${username}:${password}@${host}:${port}/${dbname}")

def db: casbah.MongoDB = MongoConnection(uri)(dbname)
```

Note, this is using Casbah API.